# How does one set Expect100Continue to false on a Coded Visual Studio 2013 WebTestRequest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, protocols, performance-testing

I am currently having an issue where when attempting to hit an external service, the webtest is throwing the following exception:

'Request failed: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF'

Investigation into this led me to this excellent article describing the underlying cause of this exception.

http://mehdi.me/a-tale-of-debugging-the-linkedin-api-net-and-http-protocol-violations/

Taking his repo program and adding request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false; into the BuildWebRequest method and pointing it at the external service we need to test does indeed, weirdly as he pointed out, result in success.

However, the coded web tests do not use the normal WebRequest object, but instead the WebTestRequest project which does not have a settable Expect100Continue field nor seem to respected ANY change to ServicePointManger.Expect100Continue.

My question is thus: how does on set this on the WebTestRequest object type? Is it possible or will some kind of wrapper be necessary?

Comment: can you show your code that you are having issues with also check out this site as well for some clues / ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784487/webclient-and-expect100continue

Answer (score 1):

In the end we could find no way to set Expect100Continue flag, as a workaround, and had to enable the UnsafeHeaderFlag.

As we could not get the load test solution to make use of a http config nor app config, we had to use reflection to set the UnsafeHeader flag value.

```
    public static bool SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20(bool value)
    {
        //Get the assembly that contains the internal class
        var aNetAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection));

        if (aNetAssembly == null) return false;

        //Use the assembly in order to get the internal type for the internal class
        var aSettingsType = aNetAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal");

        if (aSettingsType == null) return false;

        //Use the internal static property to get an instance of the internal settings class.
        //If the static instance isn't created allready the property will create it for us.
        var anInstance = aSettingsType.InvokeMember("Section",
                                                     BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                                     null,
                                                     null, 
                                                     new object[] { });
        if (anInstance == null) return false;

        //Locate the private bool field that tells the framework is unsafe header parsing should be allowed or not
        var aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing = aSettingsType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing == null) return false;

        aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing.SetValue(anInstance, value);

        return true;
    }
```

We then used a webtest plugin to ensure this could be set for a given webtest.

```
    public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsafeHeaderParsing.SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20(UseUnsafeHeaderParsing);
    }
```

This caused the response to be parsed without causing an exception. Note it does mask the original issue, but that can only be solved by the server sending the information conforming correctly to spec.